# Array(0) but the content is not empty. what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, async-await, es6-promise

I have a snippet of code which goes like this:

**getLog** (this is in a separate file)

```
export const getLog = async () => {
     return client.then(async () => {

        res1 = await method1()
        res2 = await method2(res1)
        // further parse data...
        return res4
    }
}
```

This function is async and it returns a promise which returns the result of various async calls.

**getItem** (React component)

```
const [items, setItems]=useState([])

 getItem = async () => {
    getLog().then((res: any) => {
        let finalArr: any = []
        res.map((val: any) => finalArr.push(val))
        console.log(res, finalArr)

        setItems(finalArr) 
    })
}

getItem()
```

- `res`: prints Array(0) but whe I expand it in DevTools it shows an array of objects:

  ```
    0: {name: "x", property:"y", otherProperty:"z"}
    1: {name: "x", property:"y", otherProperty:"z"}
  ```
- `finalArr`: prints Array(0) and when expanded it's indeed an **empty array**

It seems to me this is an `array-like object` (non-iterable).

**How do I extract the data from this object?**

What is interesting is that in **React DevTools** I can see the array is stored correctly in State but when I use `{items.length}` in templates it prints 0

(I am unable to produce a minimal example without rebuilding the async/await flow with mock data.)

Comment: @CertainPerformance that's a good point. However, I don't need to use the return value of the promise (since I am basically using the getItem to set react state via hooks)

Comment: My mistake, it looks like the problem is with `getLog`. Can you post the full code of `getLog`? The solution might be to use `Promise.all`, `getLog` sounds to be doing *something* other than just plain `await`ing on its top level

Comment: Are `res1`, `res2` and `res4` really undeclared (global) variables in `getLog`? Maybe something else modifies them.